# Issue with subqueries in Hive

Tags: sql, bash, hive

I am trying to run a subquery within Hive in bash. But the issue is that the compiler is saying that it cannot recognize the subquery within the query. any ideas?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"

#####################################################################
#This line will connect to the database and execute the query in Hive
####################################################################

var1=$(beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -u "jdbc:hive2:XXXXXXXXX" <<EOF
select $2 from $3.$1 where length($2)=(select max(length($2)) from $3.$1) limit 1;
EOF
)


#####################################################################
#This will output the result of the query
####################################################################

echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
echo "We are currently analyzing Table:$1 and Column:$2"
echo "The value wth a maximum length for $1 is $var1"
echo "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Comment: Where is the error message? Also, you're probably better off using beeline query parameter `...-e "<query>"` rather than trying to feed query text through `stdin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that your query will not work in HIVE because of the way you are doing the subquery. You will have to rewrite the query.

Try the next code to get the $2 that has the maximum length:

`select $2 from (select max(length($2)) as length_2, $2 from $3.$1 group by $2  order by length_2 desc) a limit 1;`

Also,you can execute the query using -e option, as @mazaneicha has mentioned.